# Python Marshmallow and PyCharm Type Hinting

Tags: python, serialization, pycharm, marshmallow

I'm interested in using the python [`marshmallow`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library for data serialization, but I'm running into an issue with PyCharm not being able to suggest the class attributes when the class is constructed using the `Schema.load` method, as shown in the examples.

Consider the following potentially contrived example:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, post_load, fields

class User:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    age = fields.Integer(required=True)

    @post_load
    def make_user(self, data, **kwargs):
        return User(**data)

class UserHolder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user = UserSchema().load({"name": "foo", "age": 42})

class UserHolderConsumer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_holder = UserHolder()

    def get_user(self):
        print("Name: {}; Age: {}".format(self.user_holder.user.name, self.user_holder.user.age))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    UserHolderConsumer().get_user()
```

The code works--meaning the data is there--but PyCharm can't suggest the class attributes. Am I asking too much of PyCharm on this, or am I missing something?

Comment: if you break it `self.user = UserSchema(); self.user.load(...)` I think then it will work... alternatively if its python3 you can annotate the type `self.user:UserSchema = ...`

Comment: @JoranBeasley it is python3, and both of those suggestions work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just for posterity, based on the answer above the following allows this to work.

```
self.user: UserSchema = UserSchema().load({"name": "foo", "age": 42})
```

Comment: That expression throws a type hinting warning because `load()` return type is a `Dict[str, Any]`

Comment: this is will throw runtime error. Since `load()` returns `<class dict>` and the `dict` will not have your attributes that you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about switching to using marhsmallow-annotations
https://marshmallow-annotations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: For visibility, this project has been has been archived by the owner

https://github.com/justanr/marshmallow-annotations